# Change C# action/delegate target: hierarchical calls

Tags: c#

Suppose I have

```
public IList<Entity> Children { get; set; }

public NotifyChildren(Func<object, bool> action, object data)
{
   foreach (var child in Children)
       if (action(data))
           /// <-- !!!! need action to work on child this time, not on the original target
           //child.NofifyChildren(action, data); <- this doesn't work because of the above requirement
           child.NotifyChildren(action.ChangeTargetTo(child), data); // << pseudocode!
}

public void SomeChangeOccured()
{
   var changedChild;
   NotifyChildren(x => x.SomeHandler(), "somedata");
}
```

How do I change the target of the action? I'm OK to pass a delegate instead of action but its .Target is read-only, too.
Currently I think doing

```
public NotifyChildren(Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> action, object data)
{
     // so that I can do method.Invoke(newtarget, new object[]{data});
     NotifyChildren(((MethodCallExpression)action).Method, data);
}
```

that is, switch from action to reflected method call... but it's a **bit** ugly, isn't it?

I have a feeling that the solution is very simple and I used to know it... just forgot.

Hm, one solution would be to have static delegate that accepts Entity as first parameter, but I wouldn't want to go this way.

Comment: Is your sample code located in the class named Entity ?

Comment: Actually it is located in the Parent class but it doesn't matter. In this example I wrote it as if it is located in the Child class.

Comment: In fact, I think this makes your question ambigous : Is Entity a hierarchical object (with a self reference) or not ?

And is your goal to recurcively notify child entities about a change that occured on your root entity ?

Finally, what is the entry point of the process ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're *specifically* asking for isn't possible. A delegate represents a statically bound method, whereas you're looking for something dynamic. To do that specifically you need reflection.

However, your code *appears* to be structured in the correct way to accomplish what you want, but the code doesn't look like it's being called correctly.

You define `action` as `Func<Entity, bool>`, but you pass in `data` (which is an `object`) rather than `child` (which is an `Entity`). It seems like you should actually declare it as `Func<Entity, object, bool>` and do it like this:

```
public IList<Entity> Children { get; set; }

public NotifyChildren(Func<Entity, object, bool> action, object data)
{
   foreach (var child in Children)
   {
       if (action(child, data))
       {
           child.NofifyChildren(action, data); 
       }
   }
}

public void SomeChangeOccured()
{
     NotifyChildren((x, data) => x.SomeHandler(data), "somedata");
}

public bool SomeHandler(object data)
{
     return true; // obviously need more robust logic
}
```

Comment: Actually it is possible with unbound delegates, but your solution seems better in this case. FWIW, you can also create the delegate straight from `SomeHandler` if you don't mind getting its `MethodInfo` with reflection.

Comment: I've fixed the signature. What you provided wouldn't work, as action will still work on the original top-level Entity - I need it to be invoked on child. You do invoke action(child, data) but it is the "static delegate" method that I don't want to use (passing _this_ as first method to static function).

Comment: @queen: As I said *what you're asking for isn't possible*, unless you go down the reflection road. Using this signature still allows for the "bubbling" approach that you're looking for. Given that the only actual method declaration is done in a lambda, I'm confused as to why you object.

Comment: The method is not invoked on the child but you have the child as the first argument of the method. Isn't that acceptable ?

Comment: It is because I'm ... a.... slightly tired I guess ;-) I _knew_ it was _that_ simple - I use lambdas all the time, but... I think it the end of the week coming.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var child in Children)
   if (action(data))
       /// <-- !!!! need action to work on child this time, not on the original target
       child.NofifyChildren(action, data);
```

WHY you call action in this loop? I think you can call it only once before foreach.

Comment: Because I need to ;-) action here is just a method name, say "HandleNameChange". And I want to call it for all children, and if children decide to, they want to call it on _their_ children. It's kind of bubble event passing.

Comment: where you pass children instance to action in this call?

Comment: or action can be changed after child.NofifyChildren(action, data); call? bu where ref keyword in this case?